# Confused on the choice between multi-website or multi-store in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9

I am building 3 magento websites using 1 magento installation, and those 3 are connected as below:

- When user enters the site domain.com, they will enter the "main" website and presented by 2 options, go to "sub" website A or "sub" website B.
- Each sub website has their own products and has a different theme, but when user switches between each sub-website, they'll carry the cart with them. In other words, they share the cart between the sub-websites.
- Once the user is done shopping, they will go to checkout on the main
  website.
- On the main website's cart, if the user clicks the product that comes from subwebsite A, they will be redirected to subwebsite A with its own theme, and this goes for another product.
- Another feature is, when user uses the "search functionality" on subwebsite A, they will only get results from sub-website A's products.

What is the best way to achieve this? Should I use 3 websites or just 3 stores under the same website?

Comment: im thinking about that too, so maybe my best bet is use multi stores and deal with it. it seems that multi stores is less complicated than multi websites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using 1 website and 2 stores

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you just can just be served with a single Magento store with some minor modifications. The main page can be a static page directing the User to two different Categories. Each of those categories can have their own Overridden theme applied and will share a cart. The only option would be to modify the search functionality to be aware of the category the user is searching for.

Comment: Excellent solution while using built-in features! +1